# Error creating Scheduler Job in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I have a Oracle BBDD with multiple schemas.

I am trying to create a Scheduler Job for delete data from a table and i have a script that work fine for one schema but fails in other two. The script is the same for the three schemas.

Schema 1: Works Fine.

Schema 2 & 3:

> Error ORA-27465: Invalid value
>   FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=00;BYMINUTE=15;BYSECOND=0 for the attribute
>   REPEAT_INTERVAL.

Comment: What's an Oracle "*BBDD*"?

Comment: BBDD is DataBase in Spanish. "Bases de Datos" -> BBDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a strange Oracle Bug. If I try to generate the job with all the properties in one call this error occurs. If i generate the Job first, and after set the interval, the error don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the repeat interval is exactly the same?

You can verify the syntax with function [EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72366):

```
DECLARE
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=00;BYMINUTE=15;BYSECOND=0', NULL, next_run_date, next_run_date);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( next_run_date );
    END LOOP;
END;


2016-10-08 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-09 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-10 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-11 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-12 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-13 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-14 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-15 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-16 00:15:00.239127
2016-10-17 00:15:00.239127
```